# What happened to Debug test in current context (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T) in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio

One of the hot-keys I used most in Visual Studio 2010 was Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T, which ran the unit test the cursor currently was on in debug mode. I think the command is named "Debug tests in current context". Now, you still have a command named `Test.DebugTestsInCurrentcontext`, but when I assign it to a key combination and activate it, it always yields "currently not available".

I do know that there is a new function in the Test menu named "Debug selected test" - but I think that mappes to the selected tests in the Test Explorer, not the file editor.

What gives, Microsoft? Are you removing features?

Comment: We're not Microsoft. You're looking for: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: I admit the last sentence was silly. I know you are superusers.com, and I hope there are some superusers on Visual Studio here. edit: ...as in - I believe the feature still is there, I just cannot find it.

Comment: In all seriousness though. If you feel like this is wrong, reporting it on Connect can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vote here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745762/cant-run-or-debug-tests-in-current-context

Comment: I got here via google when G is filtered by 'in last month', so thought it would be helpful to quickly route folks to proper connect item for voting.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but in Visual Studio 2019 at least, the following commands are the ones you want to map keyboard shortcuts to:

- `TestExplorer.RunAllTestsInContext`
- `TestExplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext`